# Find all values of K so that A is not invertible & Find all values of K so that AA^T is symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 &  0 &  0 & 0 \\
3 &  k-2 &  0 &  0 \\
k-1 &  -1 &   k+1 &  0 \\
2 &  0 &   1 &  3
\end{bmatrix}$$

## 1 . Find all values of $K$ so $A$ is not invertible.

## 2. Find all values of $K$ so $AA^T$ is symmetric

My answer so far:

**QUESTION 1**

$det(A) = 0$

$0 = (1)(k-2)(k+1)(3)$

$0 = (k-2)(k+1)(3)$

$0 = (k-2)(3k+3)$

$0 = 3k^2 + 3k - 6k -6$

$6 = 3k(k-1)$

$6/3k = k-1$

$2k = k - 1$

$k = -1$

**QUESTION 2:**

I'm confused on how to even figure this question out, where exactly would I begin?

I'm not sure if I did this the correct way, **any** advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $0=(k-2)(k+1)(3)\implies k-2=0$ or $k+1=0\implies k=2$ or $-1$

Comment: also, $6/(3k)=2/k,$ not $2k$, though for $k=-1$ they happen to be the same

Comment: $A A^T$ is always symmetric, because $(A A^T)^T = (A^T)^T A^T = A A^T$.

Comment: Note:  after answers were given, the question was edited to add a second question

Comment: You made an error in the next-to-last step, likely because of the way you wrote the left-hand side of the previous equation: it’s $\frac6{3k}$, not $\frac63k$. However, as @J.W.Tanner pointed out, you could have stopped immediately after writing down an expression for the determinant since its already factored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dividing by your variable is always a bad idea
for example if you divide
$0=x*(x-5)$
by $x$ you get $x=5$ as a solution but not $x=0$

Now to your problem:

The idea is right but

$$0 = (k-2)(k+1)$$

gives you two solutions: $x=2,x=-1$ since for each one of this values one of your factors becomes 0 and therfore your whole product.

Answer (score 1):

For a triangular matrix the determinant is the product of the diagonal elements.

By consequence the determinant is null each time a diagonal element is null.

In your case this happens for $k=2$ and $k=-1$.

Answer (score 1):

You had the right idea,

but when you got to $0=(k-2)(k+1)(3)$,

you should have concluded that $k-2=0$ or $k+1=0$; i.e., $k=2$ or $-1$.

Comment: The mistake actually is that he claims that $6/(3k)=2k$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde:  yes, I commented about that above before I saw your comment here

Answer (score 1):

I believe any k satisfies the second question.

Multipling $A*A^T$ gives the matrix:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3 & k-1 & 2\\
3 & k^2-4*k+13 & 2*k-1 & 6 \\
k-1 & 2*k-1 & 2*k^2-3 & 3*k-1\\
2 & 6 & 3*k-1 & 14 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Which will be symmetric regardless of the value of k.